# Get http://imgur.com/gallery/hot/page/1.json with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, imgur

Hello i try get this json with $.getJSON, also $.ajax(...)
but nothing...

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                url: "http://imgur.com/gallery/hot/page/1.json",
                type: 'GET',                   
                crossDomain:true,
                success: succ
            });
```

always i have errors like
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://imgur.com/gallery/hot/page/1.json. Origin my_ip is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

also i tried get jsonp request but also nothing..

```
   jQuery.ajax({
                url: "http://imgur.com/gallery/hot/page/1.json",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain:true,
                success: succ
            });
```

have enother error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

its looks like it is possible get this json with this plugin
[jquery.xdomainajax.js](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/)

Comment: For JSONP to work, the server needs to support it, not just the client.  One thing you can do is make a PHP script to get the data, then make an AJAX call to that.

Comment: yea, your are rigth, but i dont want any server side scripting.
Also looks like YQL is very good, i can create my custom "imgur" table, and send yql query there. But i need some time to understand how to do that. 
For now i made solution with this jquery.xdomainajax.js plugin

Comment: Please add your answer as an actual answer, then accept it :)

Comment: i will do that after 4 hours, stackoverflow dont allow me((

"Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 4 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution, maybe someone it will be usefull.

```
<script src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "http://imgur.com/gallery/hot/page/1.json",
                type: 'GET',                 
                success: function(data){
                           //creating json object
                           var jsonResp=$.parseJSON($(data.responseText).text().trim());
                         }

            });   
  });
</script>
```