# Trying to make an ajax call to the IMGUR api, data is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, imgur

I'm passing in authorization headers elsewhere, so I've gotten past that problem.  If I alert(data) I get an object[Object], but am at a loss as to how to extract the data from that object. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
var albumAPI = "https://api.imgur.com/3/album/" + albumID + "/images";

$.ajax({
  url: albumAPI,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) { 

    alert(data[0].link);

  },
  error: function() { console.log("ERRORZ"); },
  beforeSend: setHeader
});
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the response (`data`) either in the javascript console or even just by hitting that URL in your browser?

Comment: instead of `alert` use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` and then check the console of your browser

Comment: `Objects` are not shown in alert box.  You should try using `console.log(data)`

Comment: The accepted answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014504/get-http-imgur-com-gallery-hot-page-1-json-with-jquery shows an example of parsing a JSON response from IMGUR.  Hope that helps.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) spits this out into the console:

{"data":[{"id":"BLJg5NH","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1377916883,"type":"image/jpeg","animated":false,"width":700,"height":524,"size":76180,"views":69404,"bandwidth":5287196720,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"link":"http://i.imgur.com/BLJg5NH.jpg"},

That's for one of the images in the IMGUR album.

How would I go about pulling out individual image data next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the data, it contains a property called `data` which is an array - so get the link to the first image

```
alert(data.data[0].link);
```

Comment: Well, it's always something simple, totally forgot that all of this information was inside the IMGUR data property.  That worked great, thanks!